# WSS - Filtered Drop Down (Workaround)?

Tags: wss, cascading

Background info - I'm a Business Analyst for a company providing shared cloud solutions to pharma clients.  We use Sharepoint to track multiple things such as Action Items, Service Requests, etc.

As an end-user, I don't have developer access, but I have have access to create lists, libaries, etc with Windows Sharepoint Services (not sure of version - 3.0 or 2007?)  That said, from doing extensive research I've learned that filtered (cascading) drop-down columns are not part of the product - that figures.  Please bare with my newbie post.

Is it possible to work around this issue by using a nested IF-THEN type of statement with a combination of lookup and calculated fields?  Here's a basic scenario to illustrate what I'm looking to do:

> Custom List 1 (County)
>  Column 1 (County Name) - with 2 items:
>   1 = Morris
>  2 = Essex
>
> Custom List 2 (Town)
>  Column 1 (County Name) - with 4 items:
>  1
>   = Morris
>  2 = Morris
>  3 = Essex
>  4 = Essex
>
> Column 2 (Town Name) - with 4 items:
>  1 = Parsippany
>  2 =
>   Randolph
>  3 = Newark
>  4 = Caldwell

Using a custom list (based on these lists above) if I choose Morris in one field, can I have the Town field show only the corresponding towns - Parsippany and Randolph?

Comment: If you have MOSS 2007 - InfoPath can save your life! So make sure the version!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the SPServices jquery library on codeplex that will allow you to do such a cascade lookup/filtering... [SPServices link here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)